# Can't I open an app without a keyboard?

Tags: unity

Any application which is not locked in the Launcher can be opened via searching for it. But how do I open an application without the help of the keyboard? That is, without typing in the search field.

Is there no way whatsoever in the entire of Ubuntu operating system to open an app with only the mouse (or any other non-keyboard device for that matter)?

There has to be something like a response-accessibly central menu or something.

Comment: You can always ssh into the ubuntu machine and open the app remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done completely without a keyboard (only mouse).

- Open Dash, click on the applications icon (at the bottom of Dash)

[image]

- The first row shows most recent, below are installed applications
- Click on "See more results" to see all installed applications
- Scroll up/down to see them all

Too many? Filter the applications by category; in the right top: `Filter Results`

[image]

Comment: I was looking for something exactly like this: "There has to be something like a response-accessibly central menu or something" that houses all the applications. Thanks! +1.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two great apps in the Ubuntu Software Center. One of them is **ClassicMenu** indicator, which is a drop down menu with all the programs installed and sorted by categories, sort of like Windows XP Start Menu. Another one is **GNOME Do**, which is basically a search menu for apps. Both are located under Accessories category. I've installed both, both look great, but my verdict would be to give ClassicMenu a try. there you just use mouse to get to whatever app you need and no typing involved.

Comment: Small addition: dash board at least on my machine lags somewhat, so ClassicMenu is much faster in that respect.

Comment: Oh, and there's another application - docky, that creates Mac OS -like dock.